# How to implement custom SignInManager with tiered template?

Tags: c#, abp

I am new in using abp. Most of the samples given here are not related with the tiered template. Just with the non-tiered, standard template. But I need tiered structure. Can someone please, show me a solution how to implement  the how-to topic named as "How to Customize the SignIn Manager for ABP Applications" on the url, https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/How-To/Customize-SignIn-Manager for tiered architecture with overriding "SignInAsync" method please?
In which project should I locate the class named "CustomSignInManager" and where should I (in which project) Register to Dependency Injection for;

```cs
PreConfigure<IdentityBuilder>(identityBuilder =>
{
    identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>();
});
```

I could not make My CustomSignInManager  to work. Built-in signInManager is always overriding my custom class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, in tiered applications, you can pre-configure `IdentityBuilder` at your `HttpApi.Host` project. You can also put your `CustomSignInManager` at there.

Comment: @Cotur  Thank you. Unfortunately it did not work. What I would to achieve is to be able to sign on the abp application from my old web forms app. My old webfoms app is built on forms authentication. I want to move logged on user  in old application to new abp app without forcing him/her to log on again in new app. But how?

Comment: Did you followed that documentation fully? https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/master/Authentication-Customization/README.md

Answer (score 0):

On tiered application, you are redirected to **IdentityServer** project to login, so that's where you need to configure the CustomSignInManager.

Edit:
In your **MyProjectIdentityServerModule**, override `PreConfigureServices` like below;

```cs
public override void PreConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    PreConfigure<IdentityBuilder>(identityBuilder =>
    {
        identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<MyCustomSignInManager>();
    });
}
```

You can follow [this article](https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-signin-manager-3e858753).

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts from that link in your answer? If the link breaks your answer will lose its value.